# private folder linking to user

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have 2 folders on my Home page: Public and Private. I want the Private folder should be viewed only by that particular user. How should i link the user id with the private folder contents so that the user when logged in will view only his/her private folder???

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a kind of proxy file which checks if the user has the permission to access the file.

Comment: You link to the file via a php file e.g. `<a href="/downloads/private/userX/file.ext">` -> `<a href="download.php?user=userX&file=file.ext">`. In that `download.php` you could check if the file should be accessable by the currient user and than return the file via `readfile()`.